# Ember Test Failing For Unknown Reason

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, qunit

I'm new to Ember testing and have been trying to write up some tests.

My tests are written as such

```js
// Ember Qoute Flow Test 

import Ember from 'ember';
import { test, module } from 'qunit';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';


var App;

module("EmberQouteFlow-test", {
  setup: function() {
    App = startApp();
  },
  teardown: function() {
    Ember.run(App, App.destroy);
  }
});

test("simple test", function(assert) {
  assert.expect(1);

  visit('#/login');
  // fillIn('input.everyWeek', 'My new post');
  click('everyWeek', "everyWeek was selected");

  click('button.submit');

  // Wait for asynchronous helpers above to complete
});

test("Transaction Test", function(assert) {
  assert.equal(1, 2, "This is a bad test");
});

test("A bad test", function(assert) {
  assert.equal(1, 2, "This is a bad test");
});
```

Ember gives me this warning when I input "ember s" in the command line.

not ok 53 PhantomJS 1.9 - TestLoader Failures: client-consumer/tests/integration/QouteFlow/EmberQouteFlow-test: could not be loaded

```
    actual: >
        null
    message: >
        Died on test #1     at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:2809
            at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:5574
            at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-loader.js:31
            at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-loader.js:21
            at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-loader.js:40
            at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:5578: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'ember_qunit.module')
    Log: >
```